# Создать общий метод для двух входных параметров Java WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Существует два найденных элемента, в которых xpath одинаков, различие лишь данные в одинарных кавычках.
Нужно прописать общий метод, который будет принимать два входных параметра и заменять значения в одинарных кавычках.

Есть такой способ замены: "//*[@placeholder = '%%']".replace("%%","Series"); или
"//*[@placeholder = '" + "Series" +"']"    --- Как это можно прописать в методе?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder = 'Series']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-option[@value='n1']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Instance type']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-option[@value='CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-N1-STANDARD-8']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `String.format`:

```
void clickOnOption(String optionName) {
   String xpath = String.format("//md-option[@value='%s']", optionName);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
}
```

Comment: public GoogleCloudPage choiceValue(String holder, String option) {
        String first = String.format("//*[@placeholder = '%s']", holder);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(first)).click();
        String second = String.format("//md-option[@value='%s']", option);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(second)).click();
        return this;
    }       // Благодарю за пример, применил в коде, не хватало понимания, хотя это и азы, охватить весь материал в практике пока не успеваю.